# Set Custom Order for Facets coming from Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet, faceted-search

I'm using Solr for offering faceted navigation for e-commerce site. However I need to define the custom order for facets, but I didn't find how to do that in Solr.

Any idea how to do this? I'm using Solr Net and latest version of Solr.

Here is an example what I need to do.

Current Facets

Operating System

- Android (32)
- Blackberry OS (8)
- Windows (6)
- Apple iOS (6)
- Bada (5)
- Proprietary (2)

Price

- 10001 - 20000 (42)
- 20001 - 25000 (12)
- 500 - 5000 (11)
- 5001 - 10000 (8)

Note that it is just an example. And have many other facets.
       I want to display Price as the first facet, so need to order this    facet field as well as facet options like this.

Price

- 500 - 5000 (11)
- 5001 - 10000 (8)
- 10001 - 20000 (42)
- 20001 - 25000 (12)

Operating System

- Android (32)
- Apple iOS (6)
- Bada (5)
- Blackberry OS (8)
- Proprietary (2)
- Windows (6)

So here is how I need to order it:

1. Order Facet Field manually by some way so they are displayed on specific order
2. Order Facets as per the defined order. For OS, I ordered it alphabetically. Or may be for those facets which doesn't have order defined can be order as default based on number of count in result?

Pls advise.

Comment: whats the sort criteria ? can you give examples ?

Comment: @Jayendra I was sure you will provide me response! Just updated question with example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use facet sort per field to order the different facets respectively.

e.g. `f.<field_name>.facet.sort=count|index`

Solr only provided two options Count and Index sort. Anything else needs to implemented through custom solutions or workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Using this I can offer different order for different field. However, how does it order when we apply order using index? This is not clear. Moreover, I will be interested to know your idea on workaround to implement custom ordering for facet field and facets. Awaiting your response. And thank you once again.

Comment: which facet are you referring to ?? are you using facet range for the price ? and want to check for the Ordering of the same ?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I need to keep Price on the first place for all the facets fields. Moreover, also the order of the facets in case of Prices, like you see the changed order in example.

Comment: f.price.facet.sort=index|sort should control the range query sort as well. Also the display part can be handled at client side ? Not sure if i got it wrong.

Comment: I'm not getting how to do it on client side.. as facets are ordered from solr. Isn't there anything using which we can ask solr to order it as defined?

Comment: Or any other way to implement a custom order?

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort by predefined criteria.

`facet.sort` is what you use and it can only be: 
- count - sort the constraints by count (highest count first)
- index - to return the constraints sorted in their index order (lexicographic by indexed term). For terms in the ascii range, this will be alphabetically sorted.

Have a look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I've already looked into this. But we need custom order, where this can't be used somehow. Pls check the example for clearer idea on this. I'm waiting for your advise.