# How can I sort facets by their tf-idf score, rather than popularity?

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search, tf-idf

For a specific facet field of our Solr documents, it would make way more sense to be able to sort facets by their relative "interesting-ness" i.e. their tf-idf score, rather than by popularity. This would make it easy to automatically get rid of unwanted common English words, as both their TF and DF would be high.

When a query is made, TF should be calculated, using all the documents that participate in teh results list.

I assume that the only problem with this approach would be when no query is made, resp., when one searches for "*:*". Then, no term will prevail over the others in terms of interestingness. Please, correct me if I am wrong here.

Anyway,is this possible? What other relative measurements of "interesting-ness" would you suggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Custom Order for Facets coming from Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576517/set-custom-order-for-facets-coming-from-solr)

Answer (score 1):

> **facet.sort**
>
> This param determines the ordering of the facet field constraints.
>
> count - sort the constraints by count (highest count first) index - to
>   return the constraints sorted in their index order (lexicographic by
>   indexed term). For terms in the ascii range, this will be
>   alphabetically sorted. The default is count if facet.limit is greater
>   than 0, index otherwise.
>
> Prior to Solr1.4, one needed to use true instead of count and false
>   instead of index.
>
> This parameter can be specified on a per field basis.

It looks like you couldn't do it out of the box without some serious changes on client side or in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting idea and I have been searching around for some time to find a solution. Anything new in this area?

I assume that for facets with a limited number of possible values, an interestingness-score can be computed on the client side: For a given result set based on a filter, we can exclude this filter for the facet using the local params-syntax (!tag & !ex) [Local Params](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-LocalParametersforFaceting) - On the client side, we can than compute relative compared to the complete index (or another subpart of a filter). This would probably not work for result sets build by a query-parameter.

However, for an indexed text-field with many potential values, such as a fulltext-field, one would have to retrieve df-counts for all terms. I imagine this could be done efficiently using the [terms component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component) and probably should be cached on the client-side / in memory to increase efficiency. This appears to be a cumbersome method, however, and doesn't give the flexibility to exclude only certain filters.

For these cases, it would probably be better to implement this within solr as a new option for facet.sort, because the information needed is easily available at the time facet counts are computed.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a discussion about [this way back in 2009](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Facets-with-an-IDF-concept-td504070.html).

Currently, with the larger flexibility of [facet.json](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search), e.g. sorting on stats-facets (e.g. avg(price)) of another field, I guess this could be implemented as an additional sort-option. At least for facets of type term, the result-count (df for current result-set) only needs to be divided by the df of that term for the index (docfreq). If the current result-set is the complete index, facets should be sorted by count.

I will probably implement a workaround in the client for fields with a fixed and rather small vocabulary, e.g. based on a second, cashed query on the complete index. However, for term-fields and similar this might not scale.

Comment: There is a solution readily implemented in elasticsearch, though: Significant Terms Aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html - Offers metrics for a query relative to the index or to other query.